# Symfony2 Doctrine2 exceeding memory limit, Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, memory-limit

I have a relational database for posts.

Post Table <-- OneToMany

Post cat Table <-- ManyToOne

Category Table <-- OneToMany

If I use the Doctrine @ORM to join the tables, in Entities using annotation. I get a white screen and in the error logs show the error:

```
emergency.EMERGENCY: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1052508160 bytes) {"type":1,"file":"/[PATH TO SYMFONY]/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php","line":66}
```

I have upped the memory limit several times, from 64M to 1024M.

Has anyone else found this problem? I think that a file executing > a Gig of memory is no good.

If I write the query using the query builder I get the results I expect. I think if I could get the Doctrine relational mapping to work this would be better. does any one have an opinion on this?

I would love a bit of advice on this matter.

Thanks In advance.

Joe

------------ Edit in response to comment ---------------------------------------

Thanks for your comment @Cerad. There are only about 10 rows in the database. Also i'm in app_dev.php.
Here are some excerpts form my files.

post table

```
class Post
{
    //... ^ table collumns

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PostCats", mappedBy="Post")
     */
    protected $PostCats;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->PostCats = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

post cat joining table.

```
class PostCats
{
    //... ^ table collumns

   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="PostCats")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="postid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $Post;

}
```

the controller

```
$posts = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('comPostBundle:Post')
    ->find(7);
if (!$posts) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException(
        'No product found for id '.$posts
    );
}
return new Response(print_r($posts))
```

Result.... White screen...
I have also tried returning the results dumped into a twig template.

Do you think its ok to skip the Doctrine relational mapping and just write joins in the entity repositories?

Comment: If you happen to be dealing with tens of thousands of records then you might run into memory limits.  More than likely you have an infinite loop somewhere in your controller.  Consider posting your query code and subsequent processing.  Better yet, make a command and try to isolate the problem to a few lines of code.  And use development mode while developing.

Comment: I have edited my post with an update to your comment, thanks.

Comment: This is a no-no and the cause of your problems:  (print_r($posts))  print_r does not understand entities very well and it's causing an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes! @Cerad The "print_r" was part of the problem. I was also doing a "{{ dump() }}" in the twig template this was causing the issue also. So if I cant use dump or print_r how can I tell what's in the returned object?

Comment: Just foreach over it.  Need to do that anyways if you plan to output a table of some sort.

Comment: Yea ok cool, I just like to dump data when i'm testing stuff. I guess is will have to break that habit now.

Comment: Might also want to give: Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity) a try.  It knows a bit more about Doctrine's internal structure and won't be as verbose.

Comment: Ok cool is that an SSH thing? if so does it show the dumpdata in the SSH window?

Comment: First of all... Your debugging is terrible - use logs and testing instead of printing out errors in responses! Second of all, as Cerad said, entities don't like to be printed out... but u might sometimes need to do that - for that purpose try using print_r($array, TRUE) while logging. Sometimes helps.

Comment: @thorinkor I now know not to dump returned objects. In other systems I have used things like `print_r($array)` and it has been fine. Clearly not fine in _Symfony2_ and is also bad practise. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So The problem has been solved thanks to @Cerad.

The issue was that I was ether doing a print_r() in the PHP, or a {{ dump() }} in the twig template. these functions do not like entities or displaying large arrays/objects.

now I am just calling what parts of the returned values I want and not dumping the whole data. and it works fine!.

EDIT:

This works for dumping data

`\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($object);`

Comment: You can use a internal method to dump Doctrine2 object nicely: https://coderwall.com/p/qpdclw

Comment: wow, i spend 2hrs before i found this entry, changing the entities as it was obvious that only controllers using doctrine were failing. In fact i was using var_dump and that killed the request when some mapping between entities was in place, seems to be fine with var_export too